# How to make Flutter secret storage safe in windows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, flutter-secure-storage

Context: (this happens in Windows) I'm working on my app that is using the flutter secure storage to write and read some sensitive data, like the generated password to access the sqlite db.

For the sake of testing, I've created a second app that has the same package name and Runner.rc attributes (CompanyName, ProductName, etc), and it only performs a readAll and a print to the console.

Surprisingly it was able to print every key:value generated by my original app.

What I noticed is that the second app is able to read the key generated in the Windows Credential Manager by my original app and therefore has access to the secure files.

Is there a way to protect the Credential Manager the generated Flutter secure storage key in windows? Am I missing an woptions that should be pass to the constructor?

Comment: Hi Matt
found this https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/550
and looking at code it looks like
https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/flutter_secure_storage_windows/windows/flutter_secure_storage_windows_plugin.cpp

and in particular the 
void FlutterSecureStorageWindowsPlugin::Write(const std::string &key, const std::string &val)

ChatGPT "...uses the AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) algorithm in GCM (Galois/Counter Mode) for encryption." 
hope that helps throw some light onto how it works. Still magic to me.